# Do you need Solr/Lucene for MongoDB, CouchDB and Cassandra?

Tags: mongodb, solr, cassandra, couchdb, database

If you have RDBMS you probably have to use Solr to index your relational tables to fully nested documents.

Im new to non-sql databases like Mongodb, CouchDB and Cassandra, but it seems to me that the data you save is already in that document structure like the documents saved in Solr/Lucene.

Does this mean that you don't have to use Solr/Lucene when using these databases?

Is it already indexed so that you can do full-text search?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solr (Lucene) uses an algorithm to returns relevant documents from a query. It will returns a score to indicate how relevant each document is related to the query.

It is different than what a database (relational or not) does, which is returning results that matches or not a query.

Answer (score 6):

It depends on your needs.  They have a full text search.  In CouchDB the search is Lucene (same as solr).  Unfortunately, this is just a full text index, if you need complex scoring or DisMax type searching, you'll likely want the added capabilities of an independent Solr Index.